# Angular Dropdown Bind Id to Value

Tags: asp.net, angular, primeng

I have:

**HTML**

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="categories">Category</label>
    <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="editedOrder.CategoryName" inputId="CategoryId" [options]="categories" placeholder="Select">
        <ng-template pTemplate="selectedItem">
            <span *ngIf="editedOrder.CategoryName" [class]="'category-badge category-' + trimOption(editedOrder.CategoryName)">{{editedOrder.CategoryName}}</span>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
            <span [class]="'category-badge category-' + trimOption(option)">{{option}}</span>
        </ng-template>
    </p-dropdown>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
export class OrderDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  orderId: string = '';
  
  order: Order = {};

  editedOrder: Order = {};

  orderDialog: boolean = false;

  submitted: boolean = false;

  categories: any[] = [];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private orderService: OrderService, private messageService: MessageService, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.orderId = params['id'];
      console.log('Order ID:', this.orderId);
    });

    this.orderService.getOrderById(this.orderId)
    .subscribe(order => {
      this.order = order;
      console.log('Order:', this.order);
    });
    
    this.orderService.getAllCategories().subscribe((categories) => {
      this.categories = categories.map(category => category.Name);
    });
  }

  editOrder(order: Order) {
    this.editedOrder = { ...order };
    this.orderDialog = true;
  }

  hideDialog() {
    this.orderDialog = false;
    this.submitted = false;
  }

  onGlobalFilter(table: Table, event: Event) {
    table.filterGlobal((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value, 'contains');
  }

  trimOption(option: string): string {
    return option ? option.trim() : '';
  }

  saveOrder() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.orderService.updateOrder(this.orderId, this.editedOrder)
      .subscribe(order => {
        this.order = { ...this.editedOrder }; // Update order directly
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Order saved successfully!', });
        this.orderDialog = false;
        this.submitted = false;
        this.editedOrder = {};
      });
  }
}
```

The dropdown works as expected from User point of view, they can select an Order etc.

The issue I have is:

- Update Order requires an Id to be sent. So I need a way to send the Id not the Name. But also display the Name for users rather than the Id

I've tried changing NgModel to the CategoryId but this breaks the entire dropdown (no values show etc).

I do believe doing a lookup for the Name and finding the Id would work, but is there an easier method to just bind it within my HTML. I need to also do this with my other options in the dropdown.

Note that Order and Category are two separate entities in my backend (ASP.NET Web API). But look like this (interface examples in angular):

```
export interface Order {
    Id?: string;
    Name?: string;
    Description?: string;

    CategoryName?: string;
    CategoryId?: string;
}

export interface OrderPutDto {
    Name?: string;
    Description?: string;
    CategoryId?: string;
}
```

**Edit (additional info):**

This is how my entities are designed in the backend:

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string? CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Example Category entity:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new List<Order>();
}
```

**Update #1:**

Changed category to assign the entire object and updated html to:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="categories">Category</label>
    <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="editedOrder.CategoryName" inputId="CategoryId" [options]="categories" placeholder="Select" optionLabel="CategoryName" optionValue="CategoryId">
        <ng-template pTemplate="selectedItem">
            <span *ngIf="editedOrder.CategoryName" [class]="'category-badge category-' + trimOption(editedOrder.CategoryName)">{{editedOrder.CategoryName}}</span>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
            <span [class]="'category-badge category-' + trimOption(option.Name)">{{option.Name}}</span>
        </ng-template>
    </p-dropdown>
</div>
```

**Update #2:**

Changing to the below:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="categories">Category</label>
    <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="editedOrder.CategoryName" inputId="CategoryId" [options]="categories" placeholder="Select" optionValue="Name" optionLabel="Id">
        <ng-template pTemplate="selectedItem">
            <span *ngIf="editedOrder.CategoryName" [class]="'category-badge category-' + trimOption(editedOrder.CategoryName)">{{editedOrder.CategoryName}}</span>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
            <span [class]="'category-badge category-' + trimOption(option.Name)">{{option.Name}}</span>
        </ng-template>
    </p-dropdown>
</div>
```

Works in terms of the dropdown. When I hit save it even updates the UI but it does not send the Id to my database. (If i refresh then it reverts back to the previous value). Something with my Id not being sent to the update method. Assuming because of CategoryName instead of Id??

**Update #3:**

This is a working example with just the IDs:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="categories">Category</label>
    <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="editedOrder.CategoryId" inputId="CategoryId" [options]="categories" placeholder="Select" optionValue="Id">
        <ng-template pTemplate="selectedItem">
            <span *ngIf="editedOrder.CategoryId" [class]="'category-badge category-' + editedOrder.CategoryId">{{editedOrder.CategoryId}}</span>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
            <span [class]="'category-badge category-' + trimOption(option.Name)">{{option.Name}}</span>
        </ng-template>
    </p-dropdown>
</div>
```

- The dropdown looks fine (other options)
- The selected value doesn't look good (as it of course shows IDs). If I update the line that shows the selectedItem to:

```
<span *ngIf="editedOrder.CategoryName" [class]="'category-badge category-' + editedOrder.CategoryName">{{editedOrder.CategoryName}}</span>
```

Then when I select other options it doesn't update the selecteditem (always shows the current one) - but it does show the name. Assuming because ngModel is set to SuiteId and not SuiteName? All I want is from user perspective they don't work with IDs, only Names and behind the scenes IDs are sent.

Answer (score 0):

In function saveOrder(), there is a line "this.order = { ...this.editedOrder };"; this line code will update the order displayed in UI.

On the other hand, this.orderId  is only subscribed in ngOnInit(). I am not sure your logic behind this.route.params.subscribe(), but you can try to track this.orderId in side this.orderService.updateOrder().subscribe function to see if it is correctly updated.

PS. I am confused when reading your description in "Name" and "ID". It might be better to use Order.Name, Order.ID, CategoryName, or CategoryID directly.

Comment: So managed to get it working with just IDs, see update #3.
Only issue is when I try adding CategoryName to the selectedItem span it doesn't update, probably due to ngmodel set to the Id. (Doesn't update the selection from UI perspective but does get selected if I were to e.g. save)

Comment: Fixed the above by having a custom method to get the name by id. I wanted to avoid this but should be fine for now!

Comment: You have to choose how to deal with display value vs selected ID. One pattern is to bind ngModel to the entire object  {id: 1, name: ‘ABC’}, then display ‘ABC’ but extract id 1 when saving. See here for examples: https://primeng.org/dropdown

Comment: I am glad it works! Sarora's method is also a good point.